# Polymer 1.0 paper-radio-button does not work in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, polymer, meteor-blaze, polymer-1.0

Im creating a simple form with meteor and polymer. Not fully sure how to implement polymer's `paper-radio-button` correctly. On the page, all radios are checked. Here is my setup:

**Meteor Server:**

```
Meteor.publish('jobTypes', function(){
  return JobTypes.find();
});


//when server starts up, insert these records:
if (JobTypes.find().count() === 0) {
  //Job Types

  JobTypes.insert({
    name: 'Full Time',
    isChecked: false
  });

  JobTypes.insert({
    name: 'Part Time',
    isChecked: false
  });

  JobTypes.insert({
    name: 'Contract',
    isChecked: false
  });

  JobTypes.insert({
    name: 'Freelance',
    isChecked: false
  });

  JobTypes.insert({
    name: 'Intern',
    isChecked: false
  });

}
```

**Client:**

```
Meteor.subscribe('jobTypes');
```

**HTML:**

```
<paper-radio-group selected="small">
  {{#each jobTypes}}
    <paper-radio-button name={{name}} {{isChecked}}>{{name}}</paper-radio-button>
  {{/each}}
</paper-radio-group>
```

**Helper js:**

```
isChecked: function() {
    return this.name ? 'checked' : '';
  }
```

**Events js:**

```
'click [name=name]' : function(e, tmpl) {
        var id = this._id;
        var checked = tmpl.find('paper-radio-button').checked;
        JobTypes.update({_id: id}, {
          $set: {
            isChecked: checked
          }
        });
```

My issue is that everything is checked when I view the html page. Also the database is not being updated. Any bug in my code?

Comment: Should this: `name={{name}}` be this: `name="{{name}}"`? Not sure how data binding works in Meteor with regards to HTML element attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Just happened to me, the simplest solution is something like:

```
"click .radio-red": function(event,template) {
    template.$(".radio-green").attr("checked",false);
  },
  "click .radio-green": function(event,template) {
    template.$(".radio-red").attr("checked",false);
  }
```

This is a bug in Polymer components triggered by meteor, it only happens to me when loading the components from a **hidden. display: none** or rendered by meteor templates (spacebars).This bug is already listed in github.